# Unity Mirror - Command and Dedicated Servers. I dont know how to proceed

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, mirror, unity-networking

I'm in a very early state of the game, it is just a `Room(1-8 players)` card game.
The idea is this:
Have one dedicated server (One single scene) which contains the next tree:

```
- NetworkManager
- ServerManager 
  - Games 
    - Game 1 (Prefab 1.1)
       - RoomManager
       - InGameManager
    - Game 2 (Prefab 1.2)
      - etc.
```

I don't want to use multiple scenes in the server because I just want to store all the info of multiples games in the different managers, and instantiate the `prefabPlayer` in `RoomManager` and move them to `InGameManager` in the `startGame().`

The main problem im having is with the comunication between client and server cause its a little non-intuitive. The [Command] function in all the examples and codes i saw its done in the *client side Player GameObject* to do it on the *Server side Player GameObject*. But i dont have any idea about how to just create a game.

I have in my `ServerManager` GO a method called `"CreateGame()"`, but is not attached to any `playerPrefab` or anything known by the client directly.

Being in my *client side* I cant do a [Command] to `CreateGame` cause I cant find that function (`Ofc` cause isnt in my `playerprefabGO`) but how do I call those `"""External Methods"""` to create a game or join a game or other thing out of the proper player `(ConnectionServer.CreateGame` or something like that -.-'')

Tried using commands, `RPC`, etc. but I cant understand the logic out of the players.
`ChatGPT` abuser here and even with that I cant realize how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally solved it, not in the way I expected but finally ChatGPT give me an usefull idea:
The idea is simple, just created a `struct CustomMessage : NetworkMessage`, then did the next method :

***On Client***

```
    public void CallClientMethod(int idMethod, NetworkConnection conn)
    {
    CustomMessageSC message = new CustomMessageSC(idMethod);

    conn.Send(message);
    }
```

This is where i build the message with all the parameters i need (here i just have the idMethod i want to call on the server, but can add more properties to the struct (Just basic types)

***On Server***

```
     public override void OnStartServer()
     {
     base.OnStartServer();
    
     NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<CustomMessageCS>(OnCustomMessageReceived);
     }
```

And this `RegisterHandler` should capture the message sent and popup `OnCustomMessageReceived` method.

```
     public void OnCustomMessageReceived(NetworkConnection conn, CustomMessageCS message)
     {
     if (message.IdMethod == 1)
         Do This Method on Server
     }
```

And this should do the thing, in my opinion is a bit tedious and complex (lost like 5 days playing around) since in mirror definition they say its "easy to use". Its easy to use if you want to do a singleplayer tetris :(